# Cant extract table data since table name "User" is a reserved name

Tags: sql-server, azure, pyspark, databricks, reserved

So my problem is, I am trying to extract a table into this dataframe but I cant since the table named "User" is a reserved word...  How could I go about this to get past the problem?

Thanks!

```
attachmentDf = (spark.read 
         .format("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.spark") 
         .option("url", azure_sql_url) 
         .option("databaseName", database_name) 
         .option("user", sql_user_name)
         .option("password", sql_password)
         .option("encrypt", "true") 
         .option("hostNameInCertificate", "*.database.windows.net")
         .option("dbtable", "dbo."+"User").load()
           )
```

Error message:

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'User'.

Comment: Try wrapping the table name in `[...]`, for example: `"dbo."+"[User]"`

Comment: You should really try to avoid Reserved Words.   Take a peek at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Thanks guys! Agreed John

Comment: The dupe might be c#, but the answer is the same, delimit identify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting square brackets around the table name (e.g. `[dbo].[user]`). That tells MS SQL to use the string as a field or table name.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using a keyword as a table, you must enclose 'user' in brackets.

ex. `dbo.[user]`

Comment: Damn guys you are fast! Thanks! :)